# Google Play services only works if downloaded from Play Store

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-services

I have google play services in my unity app.

If I "*build and run*" to my android device, `Social.localUser.Authenticate()` returns `false` , but if I upload to Play store then download I get `true`. This is unusual and very inconvenient. Is there away around this? I would like to test just by "build and run" without uploading every time to play store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/1805)

- Go to https://console.developers.google.com/
- Find your project (top left corner)
- Go to credentials and click on your app
- Replace Signing-certificate fingerprint with the upload certification SHA-1 and save

It seems this issue is caused when you opt in to Google's App Signing feature

Answer (score 1):

Do you disable **Anti-piracy** option?

[image]

This option prevents users who have not installed your game via Google Play from accessing Google Play game services.

Go to **Game Services** - **Select your service** - Click on **Linked apps** - and then click on your **service's name** - Finally set **anti-piracy** to **OFF**

Hope this is what you need

Comment: Thank you, mine was OFF. so it must be something else.

Comment: @YarH You're welcome. see [this](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/1871) link. I hope it helps you